# Meteor app on nitrous.io is not starting

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

I'm trying to run my meteor app on nitrous.io but I keep getting this error – but only with my own app. The Meteor sample app runs without a problem.

I don't understand the error messages. Thanks for any help.

```
~/myapps/eboydb(master*)$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/myapps/eboydb ]]]]]                   

=> Started proxy.                             

/home/action/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.  cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: rs.initiate error: couldn't initiate : new file allocation failure
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at initiateReplSetAndWaitForReady (/home/action/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.   ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-  mongo.js:411:17)
    at launchMongo (/home/action/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux. x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-mongo.js:494:9)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (/home/action/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.  0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run  -mongo.js:592:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (/home/action/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.   ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-  mongo.js:550:10)
    at /home/action/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.   browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-all.js:195:26
```

the project on GitHub https://github.com/c6y/eboydb

Comment: looks like error belongs to Meteor MongoDB? Have you done any mongodb configurations ?

Comment: Does your Nitrous box have enough file space available, I had a similar problem when using Nitrous.io too.

Comment: @adjuke Meteor came installed on the box and the demo app does run without a problem.

Comment: I agree with @WillParker , could you check how much disk space your box has available? You may want to try increasing it.

Comment: @gmain I'm using a free account. Memory is 512 MB and Storage is 1500 MB. Seems enough for a small app to me. :/

Comment: I have run into same error. I have deleted other projects there I had, only two polymer projects. Then It worked. Issue was probably related to disk space

Answer (score 0):

@Kai As the other comments bear out....this is an issue due to restricted file space available to a free Nitrous account during mongodb intialization. I verified this on a new free Nitrous account; the first app worked smoothly but while trying to run the second app I came across the same error you reported. After deleting the first app, the error disappeared and the second app started running normally.